# RecyclerView nested RecyclerView smoothScrolltoPostion automatic scrolling is not normal

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

Now have such a demand, RecyclerView inside each item nested a vertical scroll viewpager, and viewpager is will automatically infinite loop rolling. I use nested RecyclerView RecyclerView to achieve, and the effect of rolling viewpager. I used RecyclerView smoothScrollToPosition to achieve. But in this process, I encountered a problem, is back and forth sliding several times outside the sliding of the RecyclerView, internal RecyclerViwe smoothScrollToPosition will chaos sliding. If done the same demand. Trouble share under

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRvOuter;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRvOuter = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_outer);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRvOuter.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mRvOuter.setAdapter(new OuterAdapter(this));
    }
}
```

MainActivity's layout

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#eeeeee">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_outer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

OuterAdapter:

```
    public class OuterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OuterAdapter.OuterViewHolder> {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        List<String> mDatas;
        Context mContext;

        public OuterAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public OuterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            OuterViewHolder viewHolder = new OuterViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_outer, parent, false));
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final OuterViewHolder holder, int position) {
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
            holder.mRvInner.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            holder.mRvInner.setAdapter(new InnerAdapter(mContext, initDada(position)));

            holder.mRvInner.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                    return e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                }

                @Override
                public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

                }
            });
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        SystemClock.sleep(2000);
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                holder.mRvInner.smoothScrollToPosition(holder.i++);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 30;
        }

        public class OuterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            RecyclerView mRvInner;

            int i;

            public OuterViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                mRvInner = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_inner);
            }
        }


        private List<String> initDada(int i) {
            mDatas = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                mDatas.add("" + j);
            }
            return mDatas;
        }
    }


    InnerAdapter:

    public class InnerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InnerAdapter.InnerViewHolder> {


        private List<String> mInnerDatas;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public InnerAdapter(Context context, List<String> innerDatas) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            mInnerDatas = innerDatas;
        }

        @Override
        public InnerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            InnerViewHolder viewHolder = new InnerViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_inner, parent, false));
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(InnerViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.mTvInner.setText(mInnerDatas.get(position % mInnerDatas.size()));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        public class InnerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView mTvInner;

            public InnerViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                mTvInner = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_inner);
            }
        }
    }
```

Item outer layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="i am belong outerRecyclerView"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_inner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#ffaadd"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>

    item inner:

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_inner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

[this image is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCqM1.gif)

[this is the wrong image， when i sroll outer recycerview, smoothScrollToPosition() does not work well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heI5b.gif)

Comment: Can you post a maket of your layout. Just I can't image it.

Comment: i have posted two imgaes

Comment: I'm sorry but I understand nothing all same. What do you want? How does this relate to `ViewPager`? Can u rewrite it more clearly? You'll get help more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I see your code here. Just imagine, when scroll will stop?, you will be say "if while is false or even counter will ended". will it?

Lets log 1 line above

```
holder.mRvInner.smoothScrollToPosition(holder.i++);
```

and what will we get.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            holder.mRvInner.smoothScrollToPosition(holder.i++);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
```

Comment: thanks for your anwser, but i don't know how to fix  it

Comment: @zqandroiddev please put your complete code somewhere, then i can help you to solve that problem. or create a new project and just copy past this piece of code, adapter and activity.

Answer (score 0):

At first, add listener in `onBindViewHolder` is a bad idea.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            SystemClock.sleep(2000);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    holder.mRvInner.smoothScrollToPosition(holder.i++);
                }
            });
       }
    }
});
thread.start();
```

Now, you create a new thread on each binding of item. So, you can have a few thread per single `RecyclerView`. And you cannot make +100500 threads. You should make one thread which will go through all items (visible) and scroll their position.

To get positions of visible items you should use:

```
int findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastVisibleItemPosition();
```

To get their `ViewHolder` use:

```
ViewHolder findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(int position);
```

E.g.

```
    while (isRunned) {
     SystemClock.sleep(2000);
     handler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
      int last = findLastVisibleItemPosition();
      for(int i = findFirstVisibleItemPosition(); i <= last; ++i) {
       ViewHolder holder = findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i);
       holder.mRvInner.smoothScrollToPosition(holder.i++);
      }
     }
     });
}
```

Comment: This is our product requirement.  how can i  add the condition.  Can you give me a simple plan， I want to test it

Comment: To I can help you I need understand that you want) I don't very good know English so I can't understand

Comment: Are u need to each inner `RecyclerView` scrolls to the next item per 2 second?

Comment: Then you need to save pointer to thread object instances. Now, you can make few threads per single `RecyclerView`

Comment: yes， I need to  each inner RecyclerView scrolls to the next item per 2 second。  My English is poor too。 what nationnality are you?

Comment: Gypsy and bashkir, that you like more :)

Comment: See my answer it will help you.

Comment: but i don't know how to implement it

Comment: For example, in your adapter constructor you create a new thread with body like in answer. Next, when your `Activity` or `Fragment` created, you call start thread and when they stopping you try to stop thread.

Comment: But your scheme will give you StackOverflow exception because you only add new item but you don't remove them. You should remove a first item after addition of new.

Comment: And more... If you just need to show infinity sliding of smth without ability of manual scrolling then it will better solution to use `ViewSwitcher` with animation or custom view.

Comment: thanks for your help even I still can't solve it.Our boss asked me to achieve other functions, and then have time to consult you

Comment: There isn't any difficulties. If you will need it next write me I will post full code. Just I type from my phone it isn't careful :)

Comment: If you have time, I hope you can give me the full code :)